# Ionic 2 Push Plugin: White Square while application is in Background?

Tags: android, push-notification, ionic2, ionic-native

I am using the [Native Push Plugin](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/push/) for an Android application I'm developing. I have configured an icon and an icon color for my notifications like this:

```
let push = Push.init({
  android: {
    icon: "ic_notif",
    iconColor: "#f94915",
    forceShow: true, ...
```

If I send a notification through the Firebase console (Target = User Segment -> App -> My App) and I'm in the **foreground** (the application is visible), my notification icon is displayed **correctly** in the notification area (the icon color as well in the notification drawer). However, if my application is in the **background** (or not started at all) and I send a message, I get a **white square** instead (and the icon color in the notification drawer is the default gray).

[image]

By looking through the source code, in GCMIntentService.java, I discovered that the method onMessageReceived handles the incoming message. When I'm in the foreground, the following condition is fired:

```
else if (forceShow && PushPlugin.isInForeground()) {
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "foreground force");
            extras.putBoolean(FOREGROUND, true);
            extras.putBoolean(COLDSTART, false);

            showNotificationIfPossible(applicationContext, extras);
        }
```

The method *showNotificationIfPossible* is responsible of creating the notification (icon, icon color, vibration, sound, etc.). The problem here is that it seems that the code is not being executed while the application is in the background (I'm getting the message nonetheless), specifically the following code, and that's what I think it's the problem here:

```
// if we are not in the foreground always send notification if the data has at least a message or title
        else {
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "background"); //this is not being logged at all
        ...
```

Does anyone have any idea what's going on here?. I guess I need to check the source code more thoroughly to figure it out.

Answer (score 2):

The syntax of manifiest.json file has updated and there are some new things came around, pls check in below example are those same in your case ?

`{
  "name": "Ionic",
  "short_name": "Ionic",
  "start_url": "index.html",
  "display": "standalone",
  "icons": [{
    "src": "assets/imgs/logo.png",
    "sizes": "512x512",
    "type": "image/png"
  }],
  "background_color": "#4e8ef7",
  "theme_color": "#4e8ef7"
}`

from this file you can do whatever ui changes you need.

Comment: I do have a logo.png file (512x512, white on transparent) in src/assets/imgs, but it's still not working, it's just showing a white square. What I ended up doing was to collect all my user's registration ID's, and then I send my messages to all of these IDs. It works like a charm that way.